# Getting a double line break with a concat content_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using `Rails 5`. I want to write a helper to display hashes in the view that gives the same html as the following:

```
<div class="hash_display">
  <% @file_locations.each do |k,v| %>
    <strong><%= k %>: </strong><%= v %><br>
  <% end -%>
</div>
```

The following works sort of works,

```
def hash_display(hsh)
    content_tag(:div, class: :hash_display) do
      hsh.each do |k,v|
        concat content_tag(:strong, "#{k}: ")
        concat v
        concat content_tag(:br)
      end
    end
```

end

but for some reason it is injecting two `<br>`into each line so there is double spacing between the lines. How do I fix this?

Comment: Not sure if this helps, but BR tags does not accept content, use the `tag` method instead https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/TagHelper/tag

Comment: Like @arieljuod says: `concat tag(:br)` or `concat tag.br`. Same with the your other `content_tag` calls because [**"this is legacy syntax, see `tag` method description for details."**](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TagHelper.html#method-i-content_tag).

Comment: Changing the last line to ```concat tag(:br)``` does work thank you. I disagree this is is a duplicate question. The information to solve the problem is in the 'duplicate'  but the duplicate asks a different question viz  'before the output and I keep getting the < br > characters themselves literally'.  The problem in the duplicate is that the <br> are not being escaped. The problem in my  question is not that, but that I am getting duplicate line breaks.  Can people please reconsider marking this as duplicate.